# Can't access terminal after Raspberry Pi 4 boots (custom image)

Tags: pi-4, linux, boot-issues

I am trying to build my own custom Raspberry Pi 4 image.
I have successfully built the kernel and `busybox`.
I have setup my SD Card into 2 partitions:

```
-boot 
-rootfs
```

I used a USB to TTL cable to view the kernel messages.
The kernel boots successfully but I can't access the console.
When I hit enter to access the console, nothing happens.

[image: boot folder]
[image: rootfs folder]
[image: kernel messages]

I followed this web-page:
[Build a Raspberry Pi Linux System the Hard Way](https://rickcarlino.com/2021/build-a-raspbery-pi-linux-system-the-hard-way.html)

Could you tell me what's wrong?

Comment: Try cycling through the VT's with `ctrl-alt-F[1-6]`.

Comment: I get a prompt: my_home_directory_name:login                                                                        
then a prompt to enter apassword.

Comment: And what would you like instead?  The reason it seems not to  work on tty1 is because kernel messages are being directed there.

Comment: But i couldn't  login. could you please explain further ?

Answer (score 2):

i changed the permission to access the serail device to:
`sudo chmod 0666 /dev/ttyUSB0`

also added myself to a special group
`sudo usermod -a -G dialout YOUR_USER_NAME`

and then in the minicom settings-> serial device  i changed
`hardware Flow control` to `no`

Now I can access the console.